# Batch for creatin txt from directori files

Tags: batch-file

i need batch to create txt files from zip files of directory:

This is for linux:

```
for f in *.zip; do >> ${f%.*}.txt; done
```

I need the batch for windows , thanks for advance.

Comment: I googled it and easily get [this information](http://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili). According this, it seems that there's no solution without vbs..

Comment: so you want to create one (empty) txt file for each zip file?

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%f in (*.zip) do >>"%%~nf.txt" type nul
```

For each zip file, type null into a file with the name of the zip but with .txt extension